# How to access authorization token in @nuxtjs/auth

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt-auth

I am using nuxt js + @nuxjs/auth (4.9.1) to build a project.

The problem is when I use `this.$auth.strategy.token.get()` to access authorization token the error `Cannot read property 'get' of undefined` occur.

How can I access authorization token in @nuxtjs/auth?

Comment: which strategy are you using?

Comment: only one strategy I am using. `local`

Comment: Try this.$auth['local'].token.get() nut I don't know. Log out this.$auth and look for what you need

Comment: It returns error: `Cannot read property 'token' of undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using a custom strategy defined in nuxt.conf.js as follows :

```
  auth: {
    strategies: {
      customStrategy: {
        scheme: '~/schemes/customScheme',
        ....
```

and I can get the token using the following path :

```
  console.log(this.$auth.$storage._state['_token.customStrategy'])
```